# "Dynamic" type of argument without template or downcast (?)

Tags: c++, templates, design-patterns, casting

I have my `fancyFunction` which takes a set of elements implementing interface `A`. The function does a complicated analysis of those elements, based on properties read through interface `A`. During this analysis, it will call methods of a `Consumer c` which will take the elements as arguments.

The `Consumer` is designed to take arguments of a specific type which has absolutely nothing to do with `A`.

You could imagine that `A` is an abstraction for edges in a graph. The graph is analyzed in `fancyFunction` and - for example - every time the function "crosses" an edge, it will send that edge to a `Consumer` which prints additional information stored in the edge that has nothing to do with it being an edge.

The code given below would of course not compile in a typed language (particularly C++), but leaving out the types (Matlab, Python), the code would work.

To make it work in a typed language (particularly C++), I see two options:

1. Declare the function as

   `template <class CONSUMER>
   void fancyFunction(A[] setOfAs, CONSUMER c){ ... }`
2. Declare `operation1` and `operation2` to take the most general object and then do a downcast in the implementation.

**What do you recommend to do in that situation?** (As far as I see, the visitor pattern is NOT an option.)

Full code outline (I did not use C++ in a while, so please excuse if there are minor syntactical mistakes.):

```
void fancyFunction(A[] setOfAs, Consumer* c){
  // do fancy analysis of setOfAs by properties
  // read through interface A

  double x = setOfAs[i]->getX();

  // call functions in c with arguments of setOfAs[j]
  ...
  c->operationX(setOfAs[i]);
  ...
  c->operationY(setOfAs[j]);
  ...
}

class A{
  virtual double getX();
}

class Consumer{
  virtual void operationX(??? x); // whoops, what type do we expect?
  virtual void operationY(??? y); // whoops, what type do we expect?
}

class Consumer1{
  void operationX(Obj1 x){ ... } // whoops, override with different type
  void operationY(Obj1 y){ ... } // whoops, override with different type 
}

class Consumer2{
  void operationX(Obj2 x){ ... } // whoops, override with different type
  void operationY(Obj2 y){ ... } // whoops, override with different type
}

class Obj1 : public A {};
class Obj2 : public A {};

void test(){

    Obj1 o1[];
    Obj2 o2[];

    Callback1 c1;
    Callback2 c2;

    fancyFunction(o1, &c1);
    fancyFunction(o2, &c2);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe the solution you're looking for is called the [Visitor Pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/visitor/cpp/2).

You don't want to manually cast each instance of object A in your fancy function, because that is a maintenance nightmare and a clear *code smell*.

On the other hand, what if each object automatically handled its own casting?  That's the Visitor Pattern.

You begin by defining a new "Visit" function in your base class (A), taking your Consumer as its only argument:

```
class A
{
public:
    virtual void Visit(Consumer& consumer) = 0;
}
```

You then implement this function *for every* inherited class, thusly:

```
class B : public A
{
public:
    void Visit(Consumer& consumer)
    {
        consumer.DoOperation(this); // 'this' utomatically resolves to type B*
    }
}
```

Each derived type now handles calling the appropriate operation overload, by passing the 'this' pointer to the provided Consumer instance.  **The 'this' pointer is automatically interpreted as the most specific type possible.**

Looking back through your original example code, it appears you have each Consumer providing multiple operations, and only handling a single type.  *This* pattern would likely require that you change this paradigm slightly: create a single Consumer for each *operation*, where each consumer provides overloads for *every possible* inherited type.

```
class ConsumerX
{
public:
    void DoOperation(A* a) { /* ERROR!  This is a base type.  If this function is called, you probably need to implement another overload. */ }
    void DoOperation(B* b) { /* Much better */ }
}

class ConsumerY
{
public:
    void DoOperation(A* a) { /* ERROR!  This is a base type.  If this function is called, you probably need to implement another overload. */ }
    void DoOperation(B* b) { /* Much better */ }
}
```

Then your implementation loop looks something like this:

```
ConsumerX consumerX; // Does Operation X for every type
ConsumerY consumerY; // Does Operation Y for every type
for(int x = 0; x < numElements, x++)
{
    auto element = setOfAs[x];
    element.Visit(consumerX); //Do operation X
    element.Visit(consumerY); //Do operation Y
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately - no, the visitor pattern does not help. Think about the declaration of `Consumer::OperationY`: It would be void `Operation(A& a)`. But as seen from `consumer`, the elements are NOT seen as `A`.

Comment: Read my edit, your Consumer classes would need to be rearranged to make it work.

Comment: Type is not known at compile time, so how should overload resolution work...?

Comment: Thats the beauty of Visitor Pattern - the "this" pointer knows what type it is.  The correct overload is automatically called, as long as the Consumer provides an overload for the correct type.

Comment: Ah, right. Seems to be a feasible solution, with the drawback of having code for maybe completely unrelated objects in `ConsumerX` and `ConsumerY`.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly a case where templates are appropriate. I'd even question why your `fancyFunction` is insisting on base class `A`. It should just take a begin and end iterator. I wouldn't bother with a consumer either. Make that flexible too, just take any function.

In fact, I wouldn't even write a `fancyFunction`. It already exists:

```
std::for_each(o1.begin(), o1.end(),
   [c1](Obj1 o) { double x = o.getX(); c1.operationX(o); c1.operationY(o); }
);
```